# How to tell which RequiredFieldValidator failed

Tags: c#, .net, validation

I have multiple RequireFieldValidators on my aspx page.

On the backend (C#) I want to be able to tell which control specifically wasn't valid so I can apply a style to that control.
I use the Page.IsValid method to see if the overall page passed validation but I need to know specifically which one control failed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As others have mentioned, you need to loop the validator collection of the page and check their states. [MSDN has examples here.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dh9ad08f.aspx)

```
If (Me.IsPostBack) Then
Me.Validate()
If (Not Me.IsValid) Then
    Dim msg As String
    ' Loop through all validation controls to see which 
    ' generated the error(s).
    Dim oValidator As IValidator
    For Each oValidator In Validators
        If oValidator.IsValid = False Then
            msg = msg & "<br />" & oValidator.ErrorMessage
        End If
    Next
    Label1.Text = msg
End If
```

End If

Answer (score 1):

All Validators are added to the ValidatorCollection of the Page (property Page.Validators).

You can loop through this collection to validate each control manually.

Call method IValidator.Validate();

Answer (score 0):

From memory, after calling Page.Validate() you can then check the individual validators to see which are valid using IsValid on the validator.